# Mouse over linked thumbnails to display bigger linked version

Tags: javascript, html

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Right now when I mouse over the small twitter and yelp image (each is linked), it displays a bigger version of it. However, the bigger version needs to have the same link as its smaller version. How can I achieve this? This is what I have so far...

```js
function changeImage(event) {
  var targetElement = event.target;
  document.getElementById("main-image").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="main-link">
  <img height="400" width="400" src="images/facebook.png" alt="big-image" id="main-image" />
</a>
<br/>
<div id="thumbnails" onmouseover="changeImage(event)">
  <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.yelp.com">
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/yelp.png" alt="yelp" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute of the big image `parentNode` `href` to the `href` value of the `targetElement`:

```js
function changeImage(event) {
  var targetElement = event.target;
  var bigimg = document.getElementById("main-image");
  bigimg.src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
  bigimg.parentNode.setAttribute('href', targetElement.parentNode.getAttribute('href'));
};
```

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="main-link">
  <img height="400" width="400" src="images/facebook.png" alt="big-image" id="main-image" />
</a>
<br/>
<div id="thumbnails" onmouseover="changeImage(event)">
  <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.yelp.com">
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/yelp.png" alt="yelp" />
  </a>
</div>
```